# Flutter how to get unique list of month and total their amount

Tags: flutter, algorithm

How can i make this api data create a new list with all the same month total their corresponding amounts and return a new list of just months and its total amount

```
[
 {"type": "expense", "amount": 250, "paymentDate": "22-02-2022"},
 {"type": "income", "amount": 350, "paymentDate": "22-02-2022"},
 {"type": "expense", "amount": 150, "paymentDate": "22-02-2022"},
 {"type": "expense", "amount": 450, "paymentDate": "22-03-2022"},
 {"type": "income", "amount": 650, "paymentDate": "22-03-2022"},
 {"type": "expense", "amount": 650, "paymentDate": "22-05-2022"},
 {"type": "income", "amount": 650, "paymentDate": "22-05-2022"},
 {"type": "income", "amount": 650, "paymentDate": "22-05-2022"}
]
this:
 [
  x: 2 //month in int form, y: 750,
  x: 3, y: 1100,
  x: 5, y: 1950
 ]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: I have tried this my own but i only get the total of all months not by each month

                         transactions
                            .where((element) => element['type'] == 'income').fold(0,(prev,element) => prev += element['amount']).toList()